# Whats the case in XAMPP with errno 13: permission denied?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, xampp

Using XAMPP on my Ubuntu. Trying to work with mySQL, but I get errors when im trying to create tables or do something else. I dont know, the code is really ok and actually other scripts (like XenForo) works and installing fine. Whats the case may there?

Just in case youre want to proof of sql code:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "nf");



$db->query("CREATE TABLE films(
id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
label VARCHAR(255))");
echo $db->error."<br/>";
```

So "nf" is name of database. It works from phpMyAdmin but no from this php code.

Ownership is on current user, file rights are 777.

So I dont get it why it give me the this error:

```
Can't create table 'films' (errno: 13)
```

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table 'films' (errno: 13)
Please check privileges of directory containing database. 

Whats what telling me phpMyAdmin. But as I said before, all permisions are equal to work-fine databases.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL by default witll run as the user specified by my.cnf, if at some point in the future you want to run mysql as your user you can change that on ´my.cnf´ by adding the following lines

```
user=USERNAME
```

Or if you want to add it as a startup option to mysqld or mysqld_safe

```
--user=USERNAME
```

data directory permissions are not right-

```
the default permissions for directories inside the mysql data directory 
755 (rwxr-xr-x) for mysql top data directory
700 (rwx------) for each database directory
660 (rw-rw----) for database files
```

Comment: listen maine im using XAMPP there is no special username in my.cnf, its just =mysql by default and it working fine

Comment: Also, permission for all files are the same. (scripts and folder of databases on local drive)